# How do I show the full folder path of open Nemo file browser windows when I right-click the Launcher in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, launcher, filemanager, nemo

I am using Nemo instead of Nautilus as my primary Ubuntu Unity file manager. When I right-click the icon on the launcher bar it shows the folder name of open windows, as shown in this screenshot here. **I'd really like it to show the full path, however, as frequently I have multiple windows open with the same name and can never find the one I'm looking for.**

[image]

If you tell me to left click twice on the icon to make it show them shrunk and spread across the screen I'll say I find this feature to be almost useless. Sometimes I have 10 or more windows open when working on big projects and trying to choose the right one that way is worse than using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which is also very slow and tedious.

**A simple right-click on the launcher, showing enough folder information (ie: full path) that I can identify the open windows is just what I need.**

#### Note: in case you can't do exactly what I'm asking for, alternative ways to efficiently choose the File Manager window I want (out of 10+ windows) are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It's way easier than I expected. I just needed to learn the best view settings to use for the Nemo file manager.

### Question 1. The answer to the first part of my question: **How do I see the full path when I right-click on the nemo icon in the launcher bar?**

Answer: go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> --> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> --> click the <kbd>Display</kbd> tab --> check the box for "Show the full path in the title bar and tab bars". (See screenshot below). *Close all of your nemo file manager windows, and re-open them to make this take effect.* Done!

[image]

Here's what it looks like now when I right click. Notice it shows the full folder path!:

[image]

### Question 2. The second part of my question: are there alternative (and better) ways to choose the File Manager window I want (ex: when I have 10+ windows open)?

Answer: YES! Use Tabs instead of new Windows! Open a new tab with <kbd>File</kbd> --> <kbd>New Tab</kbd> or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Now, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> to navigate to the tab to your LEFT and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to navigate to the tab to your RIGHT.

The tabs work just like they do in the terminal now, except that in a terminal you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (note you must also use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key) to open up a new Tab.

You can also use <kbd>F3</kbd> (<kbd>View</kbd> --> <kbd>Extra Pane</kbd>) to split your window when you'd like to view two folders simultaneously side-by-side.

Yaaaay! Solved!---(after about 5 years of being bothered by this).

Comment: Note: the right-click menu in the launcher is no longer the same as of Ubuntu 18.04 or so.